# Bash: How to perform redirection coming from variable expansion

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a command with a variable which holds another command that suppresses warning messages of the jar. However, it is not working as expected and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
TEST=${TEST:-2> /dev/null}
java -jar ~/bin/aw.jar ${Test}
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `java -jar ~/bin/aw.jar 2 > /dev/null` ? Do you expect the `TEST` to change often?

Comment: yes its an option set based on getopts

Comment: Also the reason for `TEST=${TEST:-..` syntax, you expect `TEST` to have some content other than appending `2>/dev/null`

Comment: yes can be set to empty

Comment: I figured it out set "exec 2> /dev/null" when option is declared

Comment: but I am still curious, what is the solution for the above question?

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is performed only if it is unquoted and present in the command line literally rather than originating from any kind of expansion:

```
$ ls
$ echo hello >out
$ ls
out
$ cat out 
hello
$ rm * 
$ echo hello '>out'
hello >out
$ ls
$ x='>out'
$ echo hello $x
hello >out
$ ls
```

In order to interpret redirection operator coming from a quoted string or an expansion you must execute the command through `eval` (note, however, that this may result in undesired expansions in other parts of your command):

```
$ ls
$ x='>out'
$ eval echo hello $x
$ ls
out
$ cat out
hello
```